# Not able to pull image from AWS ECR on my ECS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I am running ECS instance with amazon provide ECSInstance role, whose policies in JSON looks like below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ecs:CreateCluster",
                "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
                "ecs:Poll",
                "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
                "ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState",
                "ecs:Submit*",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can see ECR specific access which includes Submit* and `"ecr:BatchGetImage"` etc, using which I should be simply able to pull any images in my ECR but when I try to do that, it gives me below error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   DescribeRepositories operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::755671380468:assumed-role/ecsInstanceRole/i-0e3a77458fe98d842
>   is not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource:
>   arn:aws:ecr:ap-south-1:755671380468:repository/*

Now, As error message indicates it doesn't have `ecr:DescribeRepositories` and when I tried to add inline policy and searched for `ecr` It didn't give any result, **so how can I add this or some other policy to my existing role so that my ECS instance is able to download and push the images to ECR?**

Comment: What do you mean "tried to add inline policy and searched for ecr It didn't give any result"? You can add that line manually.

Comment: Can you explain how and where you added the inline policy? What's its json form?

Comment: @Marcin, i didn't add the inline policy as I wasn't able to find the correct one, can you suggest what should be the corret inline policy and I shall add it.

Comment: I will post an example as an answer, as I can't format code in comments.

Comment: @Marcin, thanks I am just testing this and will keep u posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to your `ECSInstance` role, and check how it goes:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a task execution role. Task execution role is the IAM role that executes ECS actions such as pulling the image and storing the application logs in CloudWatch.

You can follow this link to create and attach the task execution role - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html