# Pulling an image from my private ECR repo to an aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

This seems a somewhat similar to [Not able to pull image from AWS ECR on my ECS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988804/not-able-to-pull-image-from-aws-ecr-on-my-ecs-instance) , but that one did not solve my problem (maybe EC2 / ECS differences ?)

I have a private ECR repository, an amazon-linux EC2 instance, and a user.
upon running
`aws ecr describe-repositories`
I get

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeRepositories
operation: User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USER_NAME is not authorized to perform:
ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: arn:aws:ecr:eu-north-1:ACCOUNT_ID:repository/*
because no identity-based policy allows the ecr:DescribeRepositories action
```

I have a policy in the repository, whose json is:

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SOMETHING_MEANINGFULL",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/aws-service-role/support.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForSupport",
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USER_NAME",
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/aws-service-role/trustedadvisor.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForTrustedAdvisor",
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/SOME_OTHER_USER_NAME"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
        "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What are the permissions associated with the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no identity-based policy allows the ecr:DescribeRepositories action

Your user `User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USER_NAME` doesn't have policy that allow it to call `ecr:DescribeRepositories`.

What you configured is resource-based policy. Your user needs to have the policy as well that will allow it to call `ecr:DescribeRepositories`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html